# Is there a way to trace the DDL and DML activities performed on Microsoft SQL Server manually?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I had C4 audit enabled to log all the activities previously and it mysteriously turned off. So I was looking for a way to trace changes/updates made to the complete database in terms of it's schema and the data from an year ago to current date.

Most sources pointed towards the data stored in default trace. Unfortunately, it only stores data for last seven days.

I tried using the fn_dblog() and only saw very recent data present. Generating Standard Reports also resulted in same.

So, is there any other way to view this historical data?

Comment: If you have or your db recovery model is FULL. Did you try fn_dblog with log backup?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your Audit was turned off long enough ago to explain why you're only seeing recent data (couldn't tell you how it was turned off though).

Other tools built into SQL Server that might help you with auditing is [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and/or you could also look into [DDL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Also Extended Events have `object_altered`, `object_created` etc. which I find easier to implement and manage than a DDL trigger on every database.

Comment: (We are currently in the process of converting from DDL triggers to XE for multiple management reasons, including worrying about permissions of the caller.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good to know! XE is something I haven't explored much of yet but that's really helpful information. Seems like Microsoft spent a lot of effort offering a multitude of ways for logging data and schema changes in SQL Server. :)

Comment: Ah,@J.D. Thanks, that's great advice but didn't have both in place so those options are gone.

Comment: @AceDullur Unfortunately I think your historical audit history is gone regardless. But maybe the solutions I mentioned above and/or Extended Events (as recommended by Aaron Bertrand) could be of use to you for auditing moving forward. They each have their own benefits to help with auditing.